# Sets of Numbers that follow Benford's Law

Tags: number-theory

What are some sets of numbers from number theory (for example prime numbers, triangular numbers, etc.) that appear to follow Benford's Law?

Follow-up  Question:  What does it say about these sets of numbers if they follow Benford's Law?

Answer (score 1):

Bedford's law applies for any large, randomly produced set of natural numbers.

So if the selection is large enough and the algorithim for finding the numbers is pseudo random i.e. not picked for the specific reason of beating this law then it applies. It is simply a matter of statistics on numbers in different base systems that the leading number is most often a 1.